# react-select-plus + search not working with comma

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select-plus control in react for drop down. I am refer this demo [click here](http://github.hubspot.com/react-select-plus/). and package is [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-plus). When I search any data using space that's work fine. example are below screen shot :

[image: space between two words]

Now, My Issue is In data there are specific comma in that word then Isn't work.
example are below screen shot.

[image: Comma seperated Issue]

Now, my desire result is ignore comma in my search criteria and give me that data.

How, should I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved using filter option function in react-select-plus. The syntax is in ES 6/7 :
filterOptions = options => options;